# An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the RunInstances operation: Value () for parameter groupId is invalid. The value cannot be empt

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm getting error when creating ec2 instance from my ami:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-3e21ed44   --count 1  --instance-type t2.medium --key-name sssoft --security-groups   launch-wizard-4
```

Isn't this example same as in [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html#examples)?

It is giving this error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the RunInstances operation: Value () for parameter groupId is invalid. The value cannot be empty
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Got this when I was mistakenly combining `--security-groups` (which expects the group name) with the group ID (which is expected to be used with `--security-group-ids`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Silly mistake. In the command line the default zone was different from that of the AMI

Comment: More verbosely, use "aws config" to set the "Default region name" to match what you see in the AWS EC2 console for "Availability Zone" in the instance you are using CLI in.

Answer (score 5):

The error means the security group `launch-wizard-4` does not exist in your account.

If that security group does exist in your account, check the AWS CLI profile you're using. It uses `default` by default. But if you need to use a different profile, just add `--profile my-profile-name` to the command.

For more information on profiles: [AWS CLI Named Profiles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-multiple-profiles.html)

Comment: launch-wizard-4 does exist

Comment: Looks like I'd need to attach some IAM role to the instance?